# Is there any method to open page using a React Router v6 on button click

Tags: reactjs

Here is the App.js file which will include the main page in which i have a single button of continue. The continue button will led a user to the home page but unfortunately instead of directing a user to the home page it is opening the homepage just after the Continue button

```
function App() {
  return (  
     <div className="App"  > 
  <MainPage/>
  <Routes>
          <Route path="home" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="discover" element={<Discover />} />
          <Route path="shop/skincare" element={<SkinCare />} />
          <Route path="shop/fragnance" element={<Fragnance />} />
          <Route path="shop/makeup" element={<Makeup />} />
          <Route path="shop/hair" element={<Hair />} />
          <Route path="details" element={<DetailsPage />} />
          <Route path="bucket" element={<Bucket />} />     
</Routes>
  </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

It is the MainPage component which just contain a background image and a conitnue button
export default function MainPage() {
return (

```
    <div>
       <div class="text-center" style={{padding:"22%"}}>
            <button type="button"  class="btn btn-secondary" style={{backgroundColor:"black"}}><Link to="home" style={{color:"white",textDecoration:"none"}}>Conitnue</Link></button>
            
          </div>
          </div>
   
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the reason you see both your `<MainPage />` and whatever your other page component is suppose to show, is because your `<MainPage />` is not included in your `Routes`.

The way your component is placed makes it so no matter what the page is suppose to show, the `<MainPage />` shows at the top. Typically, you place things like a `navbar` above your `Routes` so that it always renders at the top of your page.

To fix your code, I would just move `<MainPage />` into your routers like so:

```
function App() {
    return (  
        <div className="App"  > 
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<MainPage />} />
                <Route path="home" element={<Home />} />
                <Route path="discover" element={<Discover />} />
                <Route path="shop/skincare" element={<SkinCare />} />
                <Route path="shop/fragnance" element={<Fragnance />} />
                <Route path="shop/makeup" element={<Makeup />} />
                <Route path="shop/hair" element={<Hair />} />
                <Route path="details" element={<DetailsPage />} />
                <Route path="bucket" element={<Bucket />} />     
            </Routes>
        </div>
    );
}
```

You should always place any pages you have in your app under your routes so that the proper page gets displayed on the url. In this case, because you have the path for the `<MainPage />` be `/`, then this will be the landing page for your app (the first page they see).

For any redirecting or page switches, handle it as you did using `<Link to... />`

bonus: if you want to make sure you only have a single page loaded at a time, you could also wrap your `Routes` in a `<Switch>` statement and change the `path` to `exact path` :)

Comment: It works partisi .Thankyou for detailed clarifcation.

Answer (score 19):

Have you tried useNavigate? react-router v6 no longer use useHistory they replaced it with useNavigate.

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
const navigate = useNavigate();
```

then

```
onClick={() => navigate('anypage')}
```

Comment: actually the thing is that mainpage component is called in the app.js and it is showing at the top of the page everytime

Comment: because you put it above the <Routes> so it will always show above all routes

Comment: so what should i do to remove it and called it just once before clicking the continue button

Comment: If you want it to appear on initial load but still keeps the home path, you can put it inside a modal that will display only once with the image and button on initial load. But if you want it as a separate page that will load first before home then main page should have the home path that will redirect to the other page on button click.